# Rails: For API's what should I write unit/functional/integration test cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec-rails

I have rails microservices application for which I would like to write test cases, I would like to have suggestions

1. For API what are the possible type test cases available?
2. what type of test cases should I write functional/unit/integration?
3. What is the difference in functional/unit/integration if we talk about it in the context of API's?

*Note: My application is having features like chatting, booking, payments*

Comment: In the end it depends on what your API is doing.You can write the functional tests for each of the controller actions like authenticate client, getting data from database, handling bad requests etc. If your doing any data conversion you can write unit tests for it I guess..

Comment: @uDaY I have working application with features like bookings, chatting g, authentication,  payments

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all. You should understand that API it's just a controller. So you need just to check that your api's action do proper thing (crud or any other thing) and return proper fields. Much better to move this 'thing' to some command (this is a pattern), for example gem like [this](https://github.com/karmajunkie/imperator).

In this case your tests will be easier for support/maintain. Because in 'controller' spec you will just check what do you have in response. And for 'proper action' (for example creating of record) will respond your command.
So in the end you will have test for commands and controllers. Your controller spec will just check presence of values that is returned by serializers ([AMS](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) for example).

With commands all your controllers will look like:

```
def action
  data = SomeImportantCommand.new(param1: params[:user], param2: param[:form]).call
  respond_with data, serializer: Api::V1::SomeEpicSerializer
end
```

This is pseudo code, but it shows idea of command usage.

Such approach is more complicated, but it has advantages.

1. You are using commands that can be tested separately from controllers (here you have all your business logic).
2. Difficult logic can be splitted for few commands.
3. Because of 2-nd list item you will have simply controller test, that easy to maintain. And you can be absolutely sure that front-end application/developer will recieve all necessary data.

All your specs for controller will look like:

```
it 'returns some json' do

  get '/api/v1/users'
  expect(response.status).to eq 200
  expect(response.body).to have_node(:name).with('Ivan')
  # check other fields if you want
end
```

In code above [api_matchers](https://github.com/tomas-stefano/api_matchers) gem is used to parse json response.

p.s. Also you need tests for models, but this is ordinary thing, nothing special for API.